# How to read instructions retired using the perf-interface inside a LKM?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, perf

How can I read from the PMU from *inside* Kernel space?

For a profiling task I need to read the retired instructions provided by the PMU from inside the kernel. The [perf_event_open](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) systemcall seems to offer this capability. In my source code I

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
```

set my parameters for the perf_event_attr struct and call the *sys_perf_event_open()*. The mentioned header contains the function declaration. When checking "/proc/kallsyms", it is confirmed that there is a systemcall with the name *sys_perf_event_open*. The symbol is globally available indicated by the *T*:

```
ffffffff8113fe70 T sys_perf_event_open
```

So everything should work as far as I can tell.

Still, when compiling or inserting the LKM I get a warning/error that *sys_perf_event_open* does not exist.

```
WARNING: "sys_perf_event_open" [/home/vagrant/mods/lkm_read_pmu/read_pmu.ko] undefined!
```

What do I need to do in order to get those retired instructions counter?

Comment: Are you sure you want perf / PAPI's features and complexity?  They basically virtualize  the hardware counters to make them per-task or per-process instead of per-core.  If you don't need that, you could use one of the simpler PMU-access libraries, or even do it manually.  (But if you do want to do it via perf, I assume there's a generic Q&A somewhere about making "system-calls" from inside a kernel module, not about this syscall specifically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/proc/kallsyms` file shows all kernel symbols defined in the source. Right, the capital T indicates a global symbol in the text section of the kernel binary, but the meaning of "global" here is according to the C language. That is, it can be used in other files of the kernel itself. You can't call a kernel function from a kernel module just because it's global.

Kernel modules can only use kernel symbols that are exported with `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in the kernel source code. Since kernel 2.6.0, none of the system calls are exported, so you can't call any of them from a kernel module, including `sys_perf_event_open`. System calls are really designed to be called from user space. What this all means is that you can't use the perf_event subsystem from within a kernel module.

That said, I think you can modify the kernel to add `EXPORT_SYMBOL` to `sys_perf_event_open`. That will make it an exported symbol, which means it can be used from a kernel module.

Comment: The differentiation between C global and Linux global is very useful. I'll try using the *EXPORT_SYMBOL* macro then. Thank you.